# Eclipse GMF get diagram elements programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a GMF diagram and I need to find a way to get the diagram elements from my own java class.
The idea is to have a GMF editor and generate code from the diagram created with that editor.

My first goal is to have a right-click context menue inside the diagram which offers a menue point that prints the names of all current diagram nodes in console.

I've made it so far that I have a menue point in context menue that runs a java class (implementing IObjectActionDelegate) in my plugin that prints text in the console.

But how can I get the diagram elements from that class?
Is there any way to receive a list of all diagram nodes?

Thanks for your help
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
if (page == null) return null;

IEditorPart editor = workbenchPage.getActiveEditor();
if (editor == null) return null;

if (! (editor instanceof DiagramDocumentEditor)) return null;

DiagramDocumentEditor diagramEditor = (DiagramDocumentEditor) editorPart;
DiagramEditPart diagramEditPart = diagramEditor.getDiagramEditPart();
Object diagramObject = diagramEditPart.getModel();

if (! (diagramObject instanceof DiagramImpl)) return null;

DiagramImpl diagramImpl = (DiagramImpl) diagramObject;

EObject myGmfDiagramElements = diagramImpl.getElement();

...
```